# Printing emojies with PHP + EmojiOne

Tags: php, emoji, emojione

I'm needing to create on my page an image with dynamic content.
This image needs to be transparent background (PNG).

So I searched and I figure out how to do this.
But I have one more problem... My dynamic content is an image as well... for real, it's a \EmojieOne library, that takes the code like that: ":joy:" from the database and print the real emoji with:

```
toImage(':joy:')
```

So now, when I try to use this in my imagestring (to create my image), The image generated receive the code  instead to receive the emoji image.

```
//My EmojiOne class
$client = new Client(new Ruleset());
$emojiCode = $client->toImage($emojiCode);

//Creating my image PNG
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 400);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 125);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $color);

//Printing the dynamic content in my new image
imagestring($image, 5, 0, 0, $emojiCode, $textcolor);
imagepng($image);
```

Does anyone know what I can do for the new image to receive the emoji image, rather than its HTML code in a text?